# Deleting table with foreign key assigned

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to `TRUNCATE` a table called `user_info`, however I can't since in my other table `user_profile` I have a foreign key called `f_key` which is stopping me from truncating the user_info table. I tried to drop the foreign key but without success.

I tried:

`ALTER TABLE user_profile DROP f_key`

and:

`ALTER TABLE user_profile DROP FOREIGN KEY f_key`

but neither are working. Any ideas?

Output as suggested from comment below:

```
'user_profile', 'CREATE TABLE user_profile (
 user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 f_key int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
 KEY f_key (f_key),
 CONSTRAINT user_profile_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (f_key) REFERENCES user_info (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

Comment: Some error output?!?!

Comment: What is `f_key`? Is that the _constraint's_ name, or the name of the column on which the FK constraint is defined? Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_profile`.

Comment: @Sebi2020 the error is `Error code: 1025. Error on rename of...` - seemed a bit too generic to include in my post.

Comment: So the foreign key name is `user_profile_ibfk_1` - drop that name!

Comment: @NikkiMather Edit your question to include that.  Don't put it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `TRUNCATE` for a foreign key referenced table. Imagine TRUNCATE as a combination of `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE`. Your table definition already has `ON DELETE CASCADE` which means a deleted master key will result in deletion of the child rows. However, `TRUNCATE` will skip those constraints.

Use `DELETE FROM user_info` instead.

Comment: Makes perfect sense and this solution worked a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
mysql> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
mysql> TRUNCATE TABLE user_info;
mysql> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

However, if any rows exist in `user_profile` that depended on the rows in `user_info`, then those rows would now be "orphaned".